# Solve this linear program graphically

Tags: linear-programming

> Solve the following linear program graphically: $\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x_1, x_2}{\text{maximize}} & 25 x_1 + 20 x_2\\ \text{subject to} & 3x_1 + 6x_2 \leq 50 \\ & x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 10 \\ & x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0 \end{array}$

Comment: Have you tried so solve this problem? How far did you get?

Comment: You have posed a problem for others to do but you have not asked a question. What question do you want to ask to help you do this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I would like $x$ and $y$ to take rather than $x_1$ and $x_2$.
The last sentence says they are both positive, so if we plot this, it is first quadrant.
And we plot the above 2 lines in the graph.
[image]

So we will consider the lower line, there are no intersections between first 2 lines. So we shall check on 2 points $(0,5)$ and $(10,0)$.
So putting the values of this points in $25x + 20y$. The answer is (10,0)